# Работа с Checkbox-ми в AlertDialog-e на Андроиде

Tags: java, android, checkbox, listview

В приложении на андроиде имеется Alertdialog со списком и с чекбоксами. Первый из элементов в списке называется "Выделить все чекбоксы". При этом все последующие чекбоксы при нажатии на этот чекбокс "Выделить все чекбоксы" должны автоматически выделяться. При снятии галки с первого чекбокса наоборот. При нажатии на один из элементов начиная со второго должна галочка у первого чекбокса сниматься. 
Вот мой код:

```
     final CharSequence[] items =    
    [Выделить все чекбоксы, элемент2, элемент3, элемент4, элемент5 , элемент6, элемент6] 
    final boolean[] checked = new boolean[items.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
             checked[i] = selecteditems.contains(items[i]);

     DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener DialogListener = 
                 new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {


                    if (isChecked && checked[0] == true) {
                         for (int i = 1; i<items.length; i++) {
                             ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(i,true);
                             selecteditems.add(items[i]);
                              checked[i]=true;

                          }
                      }

                    else if (!isChecked && checked[0] == false){
                             for (int i = 1; i<items.length; i++) {
                                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(i,false);
                             selecteditems.remove(items[i]);

                             checked[i]=false; 

                  ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().clearChoices();

                            }
                         }


                    if(isChecked)
                        if (which !=0) selecteditems.add(items[which]); 
                    else
                        if (which !=0) selecteditems.remove(items[which]);

                     for (int i = 1; i<items.length; i++) {
                         if (!isChecked){

                             checked[0]=false;
                             ((AlertDialog)  
       dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(0,false); 
                         } 
                     }



                }
            };
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new   
        AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
          builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checked, DialogListener);
          builder.create().show;
```

Вроде бы все работает. При снятии галки с любого чекбокса кроме первого автоматом снимается галка с первого элемента. Но при последующем снятии галки с другого любого чекбокса кроме первого снимаются все галки у чекбоксов начиная со второго. Нужно чтобы они не снимались.
Как исправить? Спасибо!

Comment: ура получилось я нашел способ.

Comment: нужно в самом начале после onClick проверить условие if (which == 0)for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) { 
                               if (isChecked && checked[i] == false) {  
                                ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(i,true);   
                                 selecteditems.add(items[i]);
                                 checked[i]=true;
                               } ........